# 'identifier expected', vb syntax error

Tags: vb.net

I'm kind of new to vb and I wanted to add items to a dropdownlist with datas from my database but I think I got the syntax wrong because I get the 'identifier expected' error.

Here is my code:

```
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader

    Dim myCommand = New SqlCommand("Select * from Vendeur", con)

    con.Open()
    dr = myCommand.ExecuteReader()


    While dr.Read()
        cboVendeur.Items.Add(dr['NomVendeur'].toString())
        dr.NextResult()
    End While

    con.Close()
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You don't need `dr.NextResult()`. And: `cboVendeur.Items.Add(dr("NomVendeur").toString())` should be the right syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VB.NET uses parentheses, not brackets, for indexing. Also, strings are enclosed in double-quotes, not single-quotes.

The following line:

```
cboVendeur.Items.Add(dr['NomVendeur'].toString())
```

should be:

```
cboVendeur.Items.Add(dr("NomVendeur").toString())
```